# Are there one-time pokemon I have to choose between in White 2

Tags: pokemon-black-2-white-2

I recently bought White 2 used, and the previous owner had made it to the Elite Four. Other than the starter, are there any Pokemon they might have chosen over another (and so I should attempt to trade that to another player and then trade back once I start anew)? A similar scenario would be the Mount Moon fossils in Red and Blue; one can only get both in the same playthrough via trading with another player.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your starter and your Fossil Pokémon

As you mentioned, and like most other games in the Pokémon franchise, you only receive one of the three [starter Pokémon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Starter_Pok%C3%A9mon#Unova) in a playthrough without trading, which is selected at the beginning of the game.

Generation 5 also has a pair of fossils, of which you can only select one during a particular playthrough of the game. Selecting the Cover Fossil will get you [Tirtouga](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Tirtouga_(Pok%C3%A9mon)), while the Plume Fossil will get you [Archen](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Archen_(Pok%C3%A9mon)). In Black/White 2, you receive your fossil from [Lenora](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lenora) in the [Nacrene Museum](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Nacrene_City#Nacrene_Museum), while in the original Black/White, you receive your fossil from a Backpacker in the [Relic Castle](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Relic_Castle).

Both versions of the game also have a set of [version-exclusive Pokémon](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Game-exclusive_Pok%C3%A9mon#Black_2_and_White_2), but which of these you have access to is, of course, determined by which version of the game you have, rather than choices you make during the game.